# AWS Glue and module not found (configparser)

Tags: python, aws-glue, configparser

I am setting up a AWS Glue job that is created on trigger from a lambda function.  The Glue job is created without issue, but I am using a custom python package that I've built (it's pure python).  When the package goes and imports, I get the following error message when the job eventually runs:

> ImportError: No module named configparser

When I run the packaged code locally thru testing, it works no issue.

Comment: Are you using Glue/pyspark or Glue/Python shell in your job?

Comment: I'm using Glue/Pyspark.